# Draw circle from GeoJSON point in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson

There is a circle in GeoJSON:

```
{
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: [
          {
            type: "Feature",
            properties: {
              shape: "Circle",
              radius: 80,
              name: "Unnamed Layer 1",
              category: "default",
            },
            geometry: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: [37.887051, 55.677584],
            },
            id: "bd256e54-98ba-4184-93a7-ff93e1562fa4",
          }]
}
```

I have tried render it using style:

```
   return new Circle({
        radius,
        fill: new Fill(fill),
        stroke: new Stroke(stroke),
      });
```

It works, but when I zoom in, zoom out the circle is always has the same radius. It is not zooming.
How to render circle properly?

Comment: I tried, has no effect. Stull wen I zoom oou the map the circle is not changes in size

Comment: Other geojson object like polygon, line save are scaled after zoom

Comment: Another assuming is to draw circle as multypolygon, is not?

Comment: Yes, but geojson has not circle type

Comment: I use this approach: `  const geometryTypes = {
    Point: [
      new Style({
        image: getPointStyle(),
      }),
    ],
    LineString: [
      new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke(stroke),
      }),
    ],
    Polygon: [
      new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke(stroke),
        fill: new Fill(fill),
      }),
    ],
  };

  return type in geometryTypes ? geometryTypes[type] : null;`

Comment: Radius of Circle style is pixels.  It should not change with zoom.  If you need it to change with zoom what are the units you want to use?

Comment: I use geojson object generated online, I dont know (:

Comment: const dataProjection = 'EPSG:4326';
    const featureProjection = 'EPSG:3857';

I do this when I got geojson object

Comment: Could you help me with that?

Comment: I need the same behavior lik here https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html but draw circle from geojson collection

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to style the point with a circle geometry

```
  style: new Style({
    fill: new Fill({
      color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)",
      Width: 2
    }),
    geometry: function (feature) {
      return new Circle(
        feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(),
        feature.get("radius")
      );
    }
  })
```

That assumes the radius is in projection units

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-8pq92u?file=/main.js